# Spark FetchFailedException- Failed To Connect to WN - Channel Refused

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

**Problem Statement:**

I am Trying To Left Join a table(A) with 2 tables (B & C) using Spark SQL. All of them contain Millions of Records with A being my left most table.
While Joining A with B,I get the result but while I Left Join with the third table, Below error is thrown:

**These are my spark parameters:**

```
spark-submit --class com.test.ClassName    Jarname.jar    --master yarn    --deploy-mode cluster    --driver-cores 2    --driver-memory 4g    --num-executors 6   --executor-cores 2    --executor-memory 4g     --conf spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false    --queue default

No. Of Worker Node: 7 (13.67 GB RAM)
Core: 4 Each

Head Nodes: 2 (27.46 GB RAM)
Core: 4 Each
```

***Below Is the Query:***

```sql
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE collated 
SELECT
    A.Field1,A.Field2,<All Fields From Table A>,B.Field1,B.Field2,<All Fields From Table B>, C.Field1,C.Field2,<All Fields From Table C>
FROM{
    SELECT  A.Field1,A.Field2,<All Fields From Table A> FROM A WHERE country="gb" and date="2019-07-04"
} A LEFT JOIN
{
    SELECT  A.Field1,A.Field2,<All Fields From Table A> FROM A WHERE country="gb" and date="2019-07-04" 
} B ON (A.Field1=B.Field1) LEFT JOIN
{
    SELECT A.Field1,A.Field2,<All Fields From Table A>  FROM A WHERE country="gb" and date="2019-07-04"
} C ON (B.Field2=C.Field1)
```

The Data Should Be inserted into the table:

**Error Message:**

> org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failed to connect to wn1-am-dev.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xx.internal.xxxxxx.net/00.00.0.00:00000